# Why we should avoid defining methods with more that three parameters, from clean code point of view?

Tags: java, c#, oop, coding-style

I read some clean code suggestions that says: methods should not have more than two parameters, and I was wondering what's the problem with it?If we have a class, and if this class has lots of methods that needs more than two parameters, what should we do then?If we define these parameters as  private in this class, and methods share these variables instead of sending them by parameters, this class wouldn't get too much dirty???

Comment: You can have a single parameter which is a class/struct having many properties instead of lots of parameters

Comment: I'm not just talking about those public methods, if we have so private methods,do you want  to make a class for each method parameters??

Comment: It's just a guideline to help writing readable code.

Comment: @Mohammadniazmand I am not afraid in "making classes" - that is one part of my daily business - it is very hard to judge which of your private methods should be refactored and in which way without knowing them and the whole context

Answer (score 2):

I think this recommendation is a good rule of thumb, but I would not treat it as an absolute rule. In some cases there simply needs to be more than three parameters.

The reasons for avoiding many parameters is that methods with fewer parameters are in general easier to read, understand and use. It may also be an indication that a method does to much work. Methods and classes are easier to understand and use if they have a single clear purpose, and do not do a lot of different things in one go.

If a method has lots of parameters, there are a few options to consider:

- Does it make sense to promote any parameters to a dependency? An indication for this is if you always use the same object for a parameter for all calls to the method.
- Does it make sense to promote any parameters to properties?
- Can any parameters be optional? Or add overloads or extension methods with fewer parameters? This can make the method easier to use if the caller does not have to care about things he does not need.
- Does it make sense to create a parameter object that contains multiple values? This might be indicated if some values are often used together. An example would be Pen or font objects used in GDI. This is mostly usefull if the object can be reused for multiple calls.
- Would it make sense move the method to a new class that takes some of the parameters in the constructor? This would also be indicated if multiple calls share parameters.
- Can you increase the abstraction level? An example would be a method to compute the distance between two points that takes x,y,z for each point. Creating a type for points, lines, etc will keep most method short and simple and easy to understand.

That said, the number of parameters is only one part of what makes a method well designed. If none of the options would make your code easier to use and understand, then let it be.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if you would use Design Patterns(but not really) your code logic would allow you to receive something like (array data, some object, some flag(optional)) as the max required parameters.

Its all about taking large code and make it as small and reusable as possible.
More or less you have data/object(s) that you process and do stuff.

This is just my opinion in regards with the suggested statement. Of course there are times when this does not apply but you can try and make pieces of code just like Lego blocks that can build something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want.

Just for code readabilty it is supposed to be as less as possible parameters in methods and there is no restriction on parameters count, you could have a 4 or 6 params and it would be reasonable in some cases.
If you don't like many private class variables you are free to pass that variables as parameters to you method, just talk to people you are work with and choose you style together.

**This is an art to decide which decision would be better for further programm maintain.**